# jar to exe file created using launch4j not opening by double click

Tags: java, exe

Plz reply....
I created a java project in netbeans. By double clicking my executable jar file application gets open but i created exe file using launch4j and by double clicking it doesn't do anything(doesn't gets open). I edited manifest.mf file still same problem. My manifest.mf looks as follows.

Main-class: mp3player.mp3gui

Class-path: lib/jl1.0.1.jar

mp3player is my package name and mp3gui is my main class. And jl1.0.1.jar is extra jar file which i dowmloaded from internet. Jlayer(jl1.0.1.jar) jar file needed for making mp3player.

Comment: Try this guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mm_-mnDKAjo Your problem looks like you've missed something, like type of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Does your file use a Frame? If it does, then it might be that you forgot to select **GUI** option under the **Header** tab in Launch4J.